# Batch files passing parameters by reference between scripts

Tags: batch-file

i can have a text file with 3 arguments: (lets call it Test.txt)

```
One
Two
Three
```

everywhere I read it says to read the list, recomended `for /f %%A in (test.txt) do ...`,

i could also load each element as

```
< test.txt (
     set /p Var1=
     set /p Var2=
     set /p Var3=
)
```

However, what if I only want the second element?

is it like passing a value?

```
call test.bat %var1% %var2% %var3%
```

and on the test.bat
    Var2=%2

---

now taking this one step further, after I have passed the variable to my test.bat

let say I make some changes to it,

```
set /p var2=%var2%+5    (I added 5)
```

how do i send this to value back to my original document,

I saw that i should use something like this

```
set /p var2="%var2%+5"
```

which makes it an environmental variable being as batch cant handle returns,

however, that is not working, when i display var2 in my main doc, it shows as a blank space

Answer (score 2):

Following your sample

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions

    < values.txt (
        set /P var1=
        set /P var2=
        set /P var3=
    )

    echo %var1%
    echo %var2%
    echo %var3%

    rem NO NEED to pass variables, as they are shared
    call secondFile.cmd

    echo %var1%
    echo %var2%
    echo %var3%

    endlocal
```

and contents of secondFile.cmd are

```
    set var1=%var1%_textAdded
```

There is no need to pass an environment variable to a child batch. They share the same variables. It is needed if the child batch waits its input from command line.

As both share the same variables, changes in child are visible in parent. IF child process doesn't use setlocal. Setlocal mark all changes in batch file local to the batch. So, if secondFile.cmd is written as

```
    setlocal
    set var1=%var1%_textAdded
```

changes in variable will be no visible in parent.

In your answer, you are using set /P var..... to asing the modified value in child. `Set /P` is used to prompt the user. Using it with a redirected file (as in your answer), gets the prompted variables read from redirected file. BUT to directly asign a value to a variable all that is needed is `set var=value`, or if you need to do some arithmetic, `set /A var=calcExpression` is used.

Answer (score 0):

```
set /p var2="%var2%+5"
```

waits for user input. the /p means prompt. take that out and it should work.